# Any way to search for text within nano?

Tags: search, text, nano

Nano is the editor I use in command prompts.

When I open a large file I would like to search for some text (think <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Ctrl + \     is useful for replace.  I never noticed, it's there at the bottom of the nano screen.

Answer (score 410, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> is the shortcut for searching. The same effect can be achieved by pressing the <kbd>F6</kbd> key. After entering the search term, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. To repeat the search, issue <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, and to search the previous occurrence, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>. In this menu, you can select earlier searches using the arrow up/ down keys.

To toggle backwards searching, you need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> in the search dialog.

For more shortcuts, press <kbd>F1</kbd>

Comment: Alt + W is closing out the iterm shell for me and not repeating the search on Mac

Comment: Alt-B isn't working for me

Comment: @ParsaAkbari Your terminal emulator is probably intercepting the keystroke. Try modifying the terminal shortcuts or use a different one. Konsole works for me.

Comment: If you type ctrl + W again and press enter, you will go to the next item. (But I agree that Alt + W is faster.)

Comment: In a Citrix window, I found that F6 worked whereas CTRL+W would close the tab in the browser.

Answer (score 27):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and find your text in nano

[Nano Basics Guide](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/nano-basics-guide.xml)

Comment: How would you search for a string that occurs multiple times, so loop through highlighting the matched text?

Comment: **F6** triggers the same action, and saves a keystroke.

Comment: What about backward search with hotkey like f6?

Answer (score 13):

> **^W**      (F6)            Search for a string or a regular expression

1. Not in all system work **F1** for help page. Try **^G**.
2. Not in all system **nano** has help page

Yep, it's just help page below. For those who see this message **[ Sorry, support for this function has been disabled ]** instead of **nano help page**

> **^G**      (F1)            Display this help text
>
> **^X**      (F2)            Close the current file buffer / Exit from nano
>
> **^O**      (F3)            Write the current file to disk
>
> **^J**      (F4)            Justify the current paragraph
>
> **^R**      (F5)            Insert another file into the current one
>
> **^W**      (F6)            Search for a string or a regular expression
>
> **^Y**      (F7)            Go to previous screen
>
> **^V**      (F8)            Go to next screen
>
> **^K**      (F9)            Cut the current line and store it in the cutbuffer
>
> **^U**      (F10)           Uncut from the cutbuffer into the current line
>
> **^C**      (F11)           Display the position of the cursor
>
> **^T**      (F12)           Invoke the spell checker, if available
>
> M-\     (M-|)           Go to the first line of the file
>
> **M-/**     (M-?)           Go to the last line of the file
>
> **^_**      (F13)   (M-G)   Go to line and column number
>
> ^\      (F14)   (M-R)   Replace a string or a regular expression
>
> **^^**      (F15)   (M-A)   Mark text at the cursor position
>
> **M-W**     (F16)           Repeat last search
>
> **M-^**     (M-6)           Copy the current line and store it in the cutbuffer
>
> **M-}**                     Indent the current line
>
> **M-{**                     Unindent the current line
>
> **^F**                      Go forward one character
>
> **^B**                      Go back one character
>
> **^Space**                  Go forward one word
>
> **M-Space**                 Go back one word
>
> **^P**                      Go to previous line
>
> **^N**                      Go to next line
>
> **^A**                      Go to beginning of current line
>
> **^E**                      Go to end of current line
>
> **M-(**     (M-9)           Go to beginning of paragraph; then of previous paragraph
>
> **M-)**     (M-0)           Go just beyond end of paragraph; then of next paragraph
>
> **M-]**                     Go to the matching bracket
>
> **M--**     (M-_)           Scroll up one line without scrolling the cursor
>
> **M-+**     (M-=)           Scroll down one line without scrolling the cursor
>
> **M-<**     (M-,)           Switch to the previous file buffer
>
> **M->**     (M-.)           Switch to the next file buffer
>
> **M-V**                     Insert the next keystroke verbatim
>
> **^I**                      Insert a tab at the cursor position
>
> **^M**                      Insert a newline at the cursor position
>
> **^D**                      Delete the character under the cursor
>
> **^H**                      Delete the character to the left of the cursor
>
> **M-T**                     Cut from the cursor position to the end of the file
>
> **M-J**                     Justify the entire file
>
> **M-D**                     Count the number of words, lines, and characters
>
> **^L**                      Refresh (redraw) the current screen
>
> **^Z**                      Suspend the editor (if suspend is enabled)
>
> **(M-X)**                   Help mode enable/disable
>
> **(M-C)**                   Constant cursor position display enable/disable
>
> **(M-O)**                   Use of one more line for editing enable/disable
>
> **(M-S)**                   Smooth scrolling enable/disable
>
> **(M-P)**                   Whitespace display enable/disable
>
> **(M-Y)**                   Color syntax highlighting enable/disable
>
> **(M-H)**                   Smart home key enable/disable
>
> **(M-I)**                   Auto indent enable/disable
>
> **(M-K)**                   Cut to end enable/disable
>
> **(M-L)**                   Long line wrapping enable/disable
>
> **(M-Q)**                   Conversion of typed tabs to spaces enable/disable

Answer (score 8):

You can search for text in nano using <kbd>Ctrl W</kbd>.

<kbd>Alt W</kbd> (or <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>) will repeat the find.  (Alternatively, leaving the box blank will default to the last text searched for.)

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl R</kbd> while in the Find prompt will activate Replace mode.

As of nano 2.8.2 (May 2017), searching also works in nano's <kbd>Ctrl G</kbd> help screen.

Comment: ```Esc - W``` did it for me in Mac OS X El Capitan, v10.11.5
thankyou

Comment: I've discovered recently, a lot of shortcuts tend to work if you press Shift as well, so Alt-Shift-W may work too.  (Which makes things a lot easier for repeated searches.)

Comment: Alt W is what i was looking for.

Comment: Note, some terminals grab `Alt W`, but `Alt Shift W` should also work